# Car hire in Austria with ski equipment

Tags: car-rentals, austria, winter, winter-sports

I'm looking at car hire in winter season (January 2020) and I have found it difficult to find a reasonable priced car with options for ski/snowboard roof rack and snow chains. Europcar is the cheapest but they don't offer neither of the thing required for the Snowboard holiday, next company is 100% more expensive.

Location wise ideally something in Innsbruck or Salzburg.

Q1. I just wonder is someone knows a local Austrian Car hire company which may offer competitive services to the big names from the comparison websites.

Q2. What to look for when using a local Austrian car hire company .i.e scam tricks or requirements for the road(other then winter tires and chains). I will be traveling to a ski resort.

Comment: Personally I stopped buying sky equipment (but ski boot): it makes a lot (really a lot) simpler to travel. Ask Europcar. I find strange they do not offer it as add-on. Snow chain: I think they are not any more mandatory, and not so useful (within few hours you get roads drivable with just winter tires) (but if you are far from a public road).

Comment: A few snowboards should fit in a decent sized car, and skis would go on a regular roofrack.

Comment: Personally it would never have occurred to me to ask a car hire company about a rack, I always good the rear seats down and make sure to get something with plenty of interior room.